# Debian Buster IPv6 Configuration

Tags: ipv6, debian-buster

My VPS provider supports IPv6. So I want to use it with Debian Buster.

I cannot ping the VM from Outside. IPv4 works fine, but IPv6 fail.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# dns-nameservers 0.0.0.0

iface eth0 inet6 auto
# dns-nameservers ::1
```

The result of `ifconfig` looks like this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 5.xxx.xx.xx  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 5.xxx.xx.xxx
        inet6 fe80::xxx:9ff:xxxx:xxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a03:xxxx:3f:28e:xxx:9ff:fe35:b164  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 66:90:09:35:b1:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15477  bytes 945788 (923.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 258  bytes 39387 (38.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 80  bytes 6480 (6.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 80  bytes 6480 (6.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Outbound Pinging works fine:

```
ping6 ipv6.google.com
```

Result:

```
PING ipv6.google.com(fra15s46-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:808::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra15s46-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:808::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=3.70 ms
```

I cannot reach the VM from Outside when I use their static IPv6 Address. Any ideas?

ip6tables -L

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  105 24367 ufw6-before-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
  105 24367 ufw6-before-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-reject-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-track-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw6-before-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-before-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-after-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-reject-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ufw6-track-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 440 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  120 19258 ufw6-before-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
  120 19258 ufw6-before-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   17  1610 ufw6-after-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   17  1610 ufw6-after-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   17  1610 ufw6-reject-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
   17  1610 ufw6-track-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   25  2470 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
   66 20913 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
    2   120 ufw6-logging-deny  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
    2   120 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 133 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 134 HL match HL == 255
    2   144 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 135 HL match HL == 255
    6   400 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 136 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 130
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 131
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 132
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 143
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 144
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 145
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 146
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 147
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       fe80::/10            fe80::/10            udp spt:547 dpt:546
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::fb             udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ff02::f              udp dpt:1900
    4   320 ufw6-user-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   25  2470 ACCEPT     all      *      lo      ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
   54 13450 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
    1   104 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
    4   224 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 133 HL match HL == 255
    2   128 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 136 HL match HL == 255
   15  1080 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 135 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 134 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 130
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 131
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 132
    2   192 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 143
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       fe80::/10            ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
   17  1610 ufw6-user-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 129
    0     0 ufw6-user-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:546
    0     0 ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:547

Chain ufw6-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    80 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW
   11  1090 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW

Chain ufw6-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-logging-deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2   120 RETURN     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-input (6 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
    4   320 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:500
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:4500
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       2a02:908:f84:9f60::/59  ::/0                 tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       2a02:908:f84:9f60::/59  ::/0                 udp dpt:53

Chain ufw6-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain ufw6-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
```

Comment: Did you check the firewall (`ip6tables -nvL`)?

Comment: The firewall seems fine, it also shows that 4 packets arrived to port `80` from the external world. The packet count on your rules can help find out whether there was a connection or not.